# Why does "[[ '>' > '0' ]]" return false while "[ '>' \> '0' ]" returns true?

Tags: string, bash, comparison

String comparison is ASCII comparison, so

```
[ '>' \> '0' ]
```

should have same result as

```
[[ '>' > '0' ]]
```

But why does the first return true(0) while the second returns false(1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[` uses the current locale for string comparisons, `[` does not.

If you set `LC_ALL` to `C`, the `[[` variant will *also* return true:

```
pax$ LC_ALL=;  if [[ ">" > "0" ]] ; then echo yes; fi
pax$ LC_ALL=C; if [[ ">" > "0" ]] ; then echo yes; fi
yes
```

My default locale, `en_US.UTF-8`, has `>` sorting *before* `0`, as per the chart [here](http://collation-charts.org/opensolaris/opensolaris.2008.05.en_US.UTF-8.html). Switching the local to `C` (collation based on raw byte values rather than culture-specific ordering), changes the behaviour.

If you're on Linux (this may also work on other UNIX brethren), the `locale` command should tell you what your current settings are, if you want to investigate/confirm:

```
pax$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I always wonder what C stands for? Isn't  locale value supposed to be set to the abbreviation of a language